# reading and processing packets in parallel using boost asio

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

I've got a thread that listen to socket, read incoming packets, process them and send them to another socket.

I'd like to accelerate this flow, by adding dedicated thread for packet processing without changing the ordering of the packets.

I've defined a thread that run the io_context of all socket activities :

```
std::thread th([&] {
  log_info("reading packets from sockets thread");

  boost::asio::steady_timer timer(read_ioc_);
  timer.expires_after(std::chrono::hours(1));
  timer.async_wait(
      []([[maybe_unused]] const boost::system::error_code& error) {
        log("got timeout");
      });

  read_ioc_.run();
  log_info("thread stopped");
});

std::thread th2([&] {
  log_info("processing packets");

  boost::asio::steady_timer timer(process_ioc_);
  timer.expires_after(std::chrono::hours(1));
  timer.async_wait(
      []([[maybe_unused]] const boost::system::error_code& error) {
        log("got timeout");
      });

  process_ioc_.run();
  log_info("processing stopped");
});

th.detach();
th2.detach();
```

in the class that handle both packet reading and packet processing. I'll get the 2 io context objects, and create a socket and a strand out of those. the socket will be used to read received packets continuously or waiting for new packet to reach the socket. the ioc_process will be used to process the packets in order (let's say it's encrypting each packet and add additional header like some tunnel protocols)

```
myClass::myClass(boost::asio::io_context &ioc_process, boost::asio::io_context &ioc_process
 ) : socket_(read_ioc), strand_(process_ioc) ... 

myClass::startReadPacketLoop() {
...
   readPacketLoop();
...
}
```

This is the loop where I enqueue the packet I just read, and go for the next read.

My question is whether I can maintain the packet ordering but have multiple threads to handle the packets simultaneously. can I implement it using shared queue or replace the strand with ioc_process? how will I preserve ordering in this case (let's say I write the packets to another socket and I want them to be in order)

```
void myClass::readPacketLoop(std::shared_ptr<Packet> pkt,
                   const boost::system::error_code& error,
                   size_t bytes_transferred) {

  std::shared_ptr<Packet> pkt = freeList.alloc();

  socket_.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(pkt->buffer(), pkt->buffer_size()),
                        std::bind(&myClass::readPacketLoop);

  boost::asio::post(strand_, [=] {
    process_packet(pkt, error, bytes_transferred);
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll walk through the issues I see in the order I encountered them reading your question

## Timers

It looks as if your threads exist for the sole reason to time 1 hour. The whole purpose of Asio is to allow asynchronous operations (such as timers) **without** the need for threads. Also, since you will have other asynchronous work pending, the timer's completions will have no effect at all.

Assuming you really meant to stop processing after a timeout, simplify:

```
struct myClass {
    myClass(asio::io_context& read_ioc, asio::thread_pool& process_ioc)
        : socket_(read_ioc)
        , strand_(process_ioc.get_executor()) {
    }

    void startReadPacketLoop() {
        log_info("reading packets from sockets thread");
        //...
        if (!ec)
            startReadPacketLoop();
        //...
    }
  private:
    tcp::socket                                    socket_;
    asio::strand<asio::thread_pool::executor_type> strand_;
};

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool process_ioc_(10);
    asio::io_context  read_ioc_;

    myClass mc(read_ioc_, process_ioc_);
    mc.startReadPacketLoop();

    read_ioc_.run_for(1h);
}
```

## Strands?

Firstly, as you probably understand the code

```
  boost::asio::post(strand_, [=] {
    process_packet(pkt, error, bytes_transferred);
  });
```

guarantees that all `process_packet` will be executed single-threaded - the strand executor makes sure that no two tasks execute concurrently. That is exactly not what you want.

> **Q.** My question is whether I can maintain the packet ordering but have multiple threads to handle the packets simultaneously.

Yes. Just keep in mind the order in which processing results become available may not be input order.

> **Q.** can I implement it using shared queue

Yes. This is the typical application of a FIFO queue. Note that an execution context *is a kind of task queue*, so you're right to think that maybe you don't need anything non-Asio.

> **Q.** or replace the strand with ioc_process? how will I preserve ordering in this case (let's say I write the packets to another socket and I want them to be in order)

If you logically want to write each packet to the output after processing, you can do exactly that (in synchronous pseudo code, for readability):

```
 while (true) {
     packet request = receive_packet();
     future<packet> response = process(request); // on the thread pool
     post(io_strand, [f=std::move(response)] {
          send_packet(f.get()); // may block until response ready
     });
 }
```

Note that here you **unconditionally** post the output operations *in sequential order* to a strand. Of course, you may have to wait for the next output packet to become ready.

> This is known as [HOL Blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-of-line_blocking)

A big point of concern is whenever (potentially) blocking operations (like `future::wait/get`) are performed on an execution service it may lead to deadlocks.

## Side Note: Executors

You may want to switch your design to passing executors rather than references to specific types of execution contexts or strands thereof. It decouples your code better. I will show this approach in the demo.

## Naive Demo

Let's create a very simple implementation that

- reads "packets" as lines of text
- processes them by bit-wise xor-ing all octets (excluding the newlines) and putting the output as an integer number on its own line
- simulate varying processing times, depending on the calculated checksum. This makes sure that processing of packets does not complete in the order they arrive
- for demo purposes

  - we reduce 1 hour runtime to 10s
  - output will be to the same socket.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/690b5167cc42ac54)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::literals;
using namespace std::placeholders;

namespace /*anon*/ {
    static std::mutex mx;
    auto              now   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
    static auto const start = now();

    static inline void log_info(auto const&... args) {
        static std::atomic_uint     tid_gen{};
        thread_local unsigned const tid = tid_gen++;

        std::lock_guard lk(mx); // avoid interleaved console output
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms tid=" << tid << " ";
        (std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl;
    }

    static void check(error_code const& ec, [[maybe_unused]] std::string_view where) {
        log_info(where, ": ", ec.message());
        if (ec.failed() && ec != asio::error::eof)
            throw boost::system::system_error(ec);
    }
} // namespace

struct myClass {
    myClass(asio::any_io_executor ex) : socket_(ex) {}

    void startReadPacketLoop(uint16_t port) {
        socket_.connect({{}, port});

        log_info("reading packets from sockets thread");
        post(socket_.get_executor(), [this] { do_receive(); });
    }

  private:
    std::string incoming_;

    void do_receive() { // continue receiving packets
        async_read_until(socket_, asio::dynamic_buffer(incoming_), "\n",
                         std::bind(&myClass::on_received, this, _1, _2));
    }

    void on_received(error_code ec, size_t len) {
        check(ec, "on_received");

        if (ec == asio::error::eof)
            return;

        // post processing task on free pool
        std::packaged_task<std::string()> task{std::bind(process_packet, incoming_.substr(0, len))};
        std::future<std::string> fut = post(pool_, std::move(task));

        // but post output on the strand
        post(output_strand_, [this, fut = std::move(fut)]() mutable {
            // note fut.get() may block
            auto response = std::make_shared<std::string>(fut.get() + "\n");

            async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(*response), [response](error_code ec, size_t /*n*/) {
                check(ec, "async_write");
                // log_info("written (", ec.message(), ") ", n, " of ", response->length(), " tranferred");
            });
        });

        // consume packet from incoming
        incoming_.erase(0, len);

        // continue receiving packets
        do_receive();
    };

    static std::string process_packet(std::string request) {
        request.resize(1 + request.find_last_not_of("\r\n"));

        unsigned cksum = 0;
        for (uint8_t ch : request)
            cksum ^= ch;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms * cksum);

        log_info("slept for ", cksum, "ms after processing ", quoted(request));
        return request + ": " + std::to_string(cksum);
    }

    tcp::socket                                    socket_;
    asio::thread_pool                              pool_{10};
    asio::strand<asio::thread_pool::executor_type> output_strand_{pool_.get_executor()};
};

int main() try {
    log_info("start");
    asio::io_context ioc;

    myClass mc(ioc.get_executor());
    mc.startReadPacketLoop(8989);

    ioc.run_for(10s);
    log_info("done");
} catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
    log_info("error: ", se.code().message());
}
```

With a simple server

```
printf "qux\nbar\nfoo\n" | nc -t -l -p 8989 -w1&
```

Prints

```
         0ms tid=0 start
         0ms tid=0 reading packets from sockets thread
         0ms tid=0 on_received: Success
         0ms tid=0 on_received: Success
         0ms tid=0 on_received: Success
         0ms tid=0 on_received: End of file
       103ms tid=0 slept for 102ms after processing "foo"
       114ms tid=1 slept for 113ms after processing "bar"
       124ms tid=2 slept for 124ms after processing "qux"
qux: 124
bar: 113
       125ms tid=0 async_write: Success
foo: 102
       125ms tid=0 async_write: Success
       125ms tid=0 async_write: Success
     10002ms tid=0 done
```

Note that the output order matches input order, even though processing completes in inverse order due to the delays.

## Trouble In Paradise

However, there are two problems.

### 1 Starvation

If input arrives too fast, output stops¹:

[image]

As stated before, `future::get()` blocks. However, that's not the real issue, since the strand ensures only one of the pool's threads will ever block on a future at a time. What's happening is *starvation*.

Of course we can "fix" it by making the `pool_` arbitrarily large. E.g. with 1'000 threads, it does complete:

```
asio::thread_pool pool_{1'000};
```

[image]

Even so, it is clear that the `output_strand_` is sometimes starved for CPU time. To really alleviate the situation, instead we can stop competing for `pool_` threads at all, replacing the `output_strand_` with a single thread:

```
tcp::socket       socket_;
asio::thread_pool pool_{10}, output_{1};
```

Indeed, now we don't see starvation anymore.

### Thread Safety

Since output is done on a different thread than other accesses to `socket_` we have a data race. To fix it, we will need to add indirection:

```
// but post output from the strand
post(output_, [this, fut = std::move(fut)]() mutable {
    // note fut.get() may block
    auto response = std::make_shared<std::string>(fut.get() + "\n");

    post(socket_.get_executor(), [=] {
        async_write(                          //
            socket_, asio::buffer(*response), //
            [response](error_code ec, [[maybe_unused]] size_t n) {
                check(ec, "async_write");
                // log_info("written (", ec.message(), ") ", n, " of ", response->length(), " tranferred");
            });
    });
});
```

Note how the blocking wait is (importantly) not on the IO thread, but the `async_write` is.

With this in place, you may have to add a work-guard, because if the input end closes the file sooner than the processing is ready, there would not be any outstanding work keeping the `ioc` alive.

```
post(output_, [this, fut = std::move(fut), work = make_work_guard(socket_.get_executor())]() mutable {
```

## Fixed Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93ac1d50236e402c)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::literals;
using namespace std::placeholders;

namespace /*anon*/ {
    static std::mutex mx;
    auto              now   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
    static auto const start = now();

    static inline void log_info(auto const&... args) {
        static std::atomic_uint     tid_gen{};
        thread_local unsigned const tid = tid_gen++;

        std::lock_guard lk(mx); // avoid interleaved console output
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms tid=" << tid << " ";
        (std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl;
    }

    static void check(error_code const& ec, [[maybe_unused]] std::string_view where) {
        // log_info(where, ": ", ec.message());
        if (ec.failed() && ec != asio::error::eof)
            throw boost::system::system_error(ec);
    }
} // namespace

struct myClass {
    myClass(asio::any_io_executor ex) : socket_(ex) {}

    void startReadPacketLoop(uint16_t port) {
        socket_.connect({{}, port});

        log_info("reading packets from sockets thread");
        post(socket_.get_executor(), [this] { do_receive(); });
    }

  private:
    std::string incoming_;

    void do_receive() { // continue receiving packets
        async_read_until(socket_, asio::dynamic_buffer(incoming_), "\n",
                         std::bind(&myClass::on_received, this, _1, _2));
    }

    void on_received(error_code ec, size_t len) {
        check(ec, "on_received");

        if (ec == asio::error::eof)
            return;

        // post processing task on free pool
        std::packaged_task<std::string()> task{std::bind(process_packet, incoming_.substr(0, len))};
        std::future<std::string> fut = post(pool_, std::move(task));

        // but post output from the strand
        post(output_, [this, fut = std::move(fut), work = make_work_guard(socket_.get_executor())]() mutable {
            // note fut.get() may block
            auto response = std::make_shared<std::string>(fut.get() + "\n");

            post(socket_.get_executor(), [this, response] {
                async_write(                          //
                    socket_, asio::buffer(*response), //
                    [response](error_code ec, [[maybe_unused]] size_t n) {
                        check(ec, "async_write");
                        // log_info("written (", ec.message(), ") ", n, " of ", response->length(), " tranferred");
                    });
            });
        });

        // consume packet from incoming
        incoming_.erase(0, len);

        // continue receiving packets
        do_receive();
    };

    static std::string process_packet(std::string request) {
        request.resize(1 + request.find_last_not_of("\r\n"));

        unsigned cksum = 0;
        for (uint8_t ch : request)
            cksum ^= ch;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms * cksum);

        log_info("slept for ", cksum, "ms after processing ", quoted(request));
        return request + ": " + std::to_string(cksum);
    }

    tcp::socket       socket_;
    asio::thread_pool pool_{10}, output_{1};
};

int main() try {
    log_info("start");
    asio::io_context ioc;

    myClass mc(ioc.get_executor());
    mc.startReadPacketLoop(8989);

    ioc.run_for(1h);
    log_info("done");
} catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
    log_info("error: ", se.code().message());
}
```

## Summary/Conclusion

This approach isn't optimal. It allocates unncessarily, uses blocking operations and so on.

You could optimize by using a ringbuffer/disruptor style container for the output queue. You'll need to use a monotonously increasing id for processed packets. Bonus, if you make sure the container has suitable reference stability, you can avoid dynamically allocating the shared responses.

---

¹ input.txt generated with `sort -R /etc/dictionaries-common/words | grep -v \' > input.txt`

Comment: Here's a version that uses the disruptor style using `std::deque`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b7c82d5775bd4fb Note that you will still want to have some back-pressure to avoid excessive queue depths, see different timings live: http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/c2252596-2d45-475b-a291-8e0704036954/out-2023-03-24_03.49.48.mp4